# Repeating elements/links in org pages to be published as html?

Tags: org-mode

Is there a simple way to add something like the [`{Back to Worg's index}`](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/index.html) to every .org page in a directory which I plan to publish with `org-publish-project-alist`? Is this accomplished with a `#+` tag, or some definition in the .css file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at how they did it on [Worg](http://orgmode.org/worg/sources/), and it doesn't look like CSS.

There are a few ways you might be able to do so.

Create a generic file that only includes the details you want in each file.  For example:

```
[[./index.org][Back to index]]
```

Then use `#+include: <filename>` at the location in your file where you want the line.  (See [Include Files](http://orgmode.org/manual/Include-files.html))

Alternately you could define a macro in a setupfile (See [In-Buffer Settings](http://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-settings.html)) that is the definition of the link (or multiple link choices)

```
#+macro: toIndex [[./index.org][Back to index]]
```

In both cases it is worth noting that the relative paths are based on the exported file.  So a `[[../index.org]]` will always point to the index.org file in the parent directory, no matter where the setupfile is.

Comment: Both are brilliant! But I like the `include` option as it seems to be more general in the sense of allowing me to use one include file per directory.

Comment: If you always use `index.org` as your page to go back to in each directory, you can simply use a single file that always goes `[[../index.org]]` for the parent or `[[./index.org]]` for the same level.  Of course that depends on the structure you choose to create.